# Chatter doesn't recognize Auth::user in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

Hell0, i don't have any errors and everything during installation (using this instructions):

```
https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter
```

passed well with 0 errors, everything looks fine, but it dose't recognize my user when i'm logged in.

dd(Auth::user()); returns false.

If I'm using "Auth::guard('webfront')->user()" instead "Auth::user()" in the views & controllers it's getting the session and shows me the form to post. But than when i try to post, it's redirecting me back to login page (while i'm still logged in).

There is just one thing that is bothering me... The main system controllers are in:

"App\Http\Controllers\Frontend..." and "App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth"

and the same folder names for the views too. At first when i try to force "use Auth;" to use "App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth;" but than it return's that can't find the class "App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth"

Does anybody had this problem? Any solution? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: For everyone who is having the same problem. You have to edit the chatter.php config file, and add the id of your used middleware into their fields like for example:

```
'middleware' => [
    'global'     => ['web'],
    'home'       => [],
    'discussion' => [
        'index'   => [],
        'show'    => [],
        'create'  => ['auth:webfront'],
        'store'   => ['auth:webfront'],
        'destroy' => ['auth:webfront'],
        'edit'    => ['auth:webfront'],
        'update'  => ['auth:webfront'],
    ],
    'post' => [
        'index'   => [],
        'show'    => [],
        'create'  => ['auth:webfront'],
        'store'   => ['auth:webfront'],
        'destroy' => ['auth:webfront'],
        'edit'    => ['auth:webfront'],
        'update'  => ['auth:webfront'],
    ],
    'category' => [
        'show' => [],
    ],
],
```